# Using `react-oidc-context` and storing the `access_token` and `refresh_token` together

Tags: oauth2, asp.net-core, react, oidc

I am looking for a "best practises" approach for creating SPAs protected using OIDC + PKCE.

Most of our applications are hosted on two independent web servers with a load balancer routing requests to them in a round-robin configuration. Our SPAs are almost always accompanied by an API which is also protected using OIDC. That API is also hosted on the same two independent web servers with a load balancer routing request to them in a round-robin configuration. OIDC is using PKCE, and our IDaaS supports refresh token rotation.

I've come across the `react-oidc-context` SDK ([click here](https://github.com/authts/react-oidc-context)) and noticed that it stores the `access_token` and `refresh_token` together in the browser session storage. I've read elsewhere on the web that the best practice is to store the `access_token` in a closure variable or service worker and the `refresh_token` in the localStorage.

**Question #1:** Are there any security concerns with keeping the `access_token` together with the `refresh_token` in the session storage?

**Question #2:** I've read and am familiar with recommendations to keep the `access_token` in an HTTP-only cookie on the server. Does it matter that the API is hosted on two independent web servers? Meaning that if the HTTP-only cookie is issued by Web Server #1, will Web Server #2 have access to the `access_token` inside of the HTTP-only cookie?